# exposing traefik dashboard using own hostname

Tags: docker, dockerfile, traefik

i would like to expose the traefik dashboard on an external url say `https://example.com/dashboard` but i keep running into a 404 not found error, despite already specifying the routing rule for the host and path prefix. i am able to access the dashboard on localhost port 8080 but unable to do so when i try to access it via the url

here is the configuration in `route.toml`

```
[http.routers]
  [http.routers.traefik]
    rule = "Host(`example.com`) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`))"
    middlewares = [] 
    service = "api@internal"
    entryPoints = ["traefik"]
    [http.routers.traefik.tls]
      options = "default"
```

this is my `traefik.toml`

```
################################################################
# Global configuration
################################################################
[global]
  checkNewVersion = false
  sendAnonymousUsage = false


################################################################
# Entrypoints configuration
################################################################

# Entrypoints definition
[entryPoints]

# Dashboard and API
  [entryPoints.traefik]
    address = ":8080"
    [entryPoints.traefik.http.tls]

  [entryPoints.ping]
    address = ":8082"

  [entryPoints.web-secure]
    address = ":8443"

    # TLS is enabled by having this empty option
    [entryPoints.web-secure.http.tls]

################################################################
# API and dashboard configuration
################################################################

# Enable API and dashboard
[api]
  dashboard = true
  debug = true

################################################################
# File-Based Configuration Backend
################################################################

[providers]
  [providers.file]
    directory = "/config"
    watch = "true"
```

and here is my dockerfile

```
FROM docker.odyssey.rowini.net/traefik:2.10.1
VOLUME /etc/docker/container-data/traefik:/etc/traefik
VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
VOLUME /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
COPY traefik.toml /traefik.toml
COPY middleware.toml /config/middleware.toml
COPY tls.toml /config/tls.toml
COPY certs /certs
COPY route.toml /config/route.toml
EXPOSE 8443 8080 8082
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
```

been trying to find everywhere online but cant seem to find anything to any help would be greatly appreciated